# calculate sum of cells with certain criteria google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

i have the following table in google spreadsheet and i'm trying to calculate the total cost of items in each category.

i've tried `SUMIF` but keep getting errors and such. what is the correct formula to do this?

```
    A Item          B cost          C category
    airbnb inc      $1,867.00        airbnb
    airbnb inc      $1,114.00        airbnb
    apple           $1,114.00        tech
    google          $1,114.00        tech
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029300/google-spreadsheet-sum-of-every-row-where-two-conditions-are-met?rq=1

Comment: @PreetSangha that seems different and super complicated. im somewhat new to this yet i think there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: try this: `=SUMIF(C1:C10,"airbnb",B1:B10)`

Comment: @simoco okay that works! how would i adjust to factor in all of column C and B? ie the entire sheet in those columns.

Comment: not sure what do you mean..somthinng like this: `=SUMIF(C:C,"airbnb",B:B)`?

Comment: yea that's what i want but i'm getting a #REF error... any thoughts why? appreciate your help.

Comment: it seems that your column B contains `#REF` error, and formula tries to sum this value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on web apps

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28366631/1677912)?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with the QUERY function:

```
=query(A1:C5,"select A,sum(B),C group by C,A",1)
```

Assuming that your data is in the first 5 rows of the A,B,C columns. (First row beeng the header).

Try this and give me a feedback if it works.